# Cron working partially

Tags: cron-task

I just created a script to get document volumes from the Content Manager OnDemand database. It goes like this:

```
    dateYesterday=`TZ=GMT+20 date +"%Y%m%d"`
    fileToday="GrossVolumes_AsOf_"$dateYesterday
    touch $fileToday
    chmod 770 $fileToday
    db2 connect to ARCHIVEPN >/dev/null
    db2 -tmf CMOD_Gross_Volumes.sql  | tee -a $fileToday
    db2 quit
```

It works just fine when invoked directly from the shell and generates a file like 'GrossVolumes_AsOn_mmddYYYY' with all the details present:

```
    /home/myprompt> . createMonthlyReport
```

But when I schedule it via a cron entry, it creates a zero-byte file and the details are nowhere to be seen.

Here is the cron entry:

```
    54  11  *  *  *  /home/myprompt/createMonthlyReport
```

Comment: I've moved your solution to a separate community wiki.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

It appears that the cron-task would need the fully-qualified path of the program (db2 in this case) to get going. So, I basically added the absolute path in the script (as can be seen below) to make it functional. It might not be the most efficient way but works nonetheless.

```
dateYesterday=`TZ=GMT+20 date +"%Y%m%d"`
fileToday="GrossVolumes_AsOf_"$dateYesterday
touch $fileToday
chmod 770 $fileToday
/path/to/db2_bin_directory/db2 connect to ARCHIVEPN >/dev/null
/path/to/db2_bin_directory/db2 -tmf CMOD_Gross_Volumes.sql  | tee -a $fileToday
/path/to/db2_bin_directory/db2 quit
```